# AnyLogic - Using the Key-Value database connectivity object

Tags: database, anylogic

I'm using a database to pass data to my model.  This is very convenient if a little slow (as I need to constantly query the DB during the run) but that is another story.

AnyLogic has a great looking object on the "Connectivity" pallet called a Key-Value Table which enables you to create a key-value (hashmap?) by simply specifying things like the table name and the key and value fields.  It also requires you to specify the database - which is where my problem arises...

The database I am using is the internal database which is accessible from getEngine().getModelDatabase() however this is of type ModelDatabase whereas the Key-Value object expects a database of the type Database.  Database and ModelDatabase seem to be from different inheritance trees so I am unable to cast the ModelDatabase to Database.

This is what I tried:

[image]

But I get the error "Cannot cast from ModelDatabase to Database" when compiling.

My database table looks like this:

[image]

I'd prefer to not have to import the database as a separate database object if possible.

Has anyone tried to use this object with the ModelDatabase and come across a solution to this problem?

Comment: Why not to read these from Excel or CSV? I never use AnyLogic internal database. It is slow and problematic.

Comment: I appreciate the response but it was not helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the key-value table if you use the internal database (which I use all the time :D ).  Just use the "database query wizard" (see help) to read data and turn it into a LHM yourself. The key-value object is a remnant from before the internal dbase was even around...
[image]

Comment: True..but if you don't work with 20 million rows..:/

Comment: Thanks Ben, another post of wisdom.  It's a pity as that really was a very easy to use object for my use case.  Never mind though, your solution solves my problem.